# Does anything happen if I collect all the code cubes?

Tags: kirby-planet-robobot

I know if I collect all the code cubes in the regular levels in a world, I get an extra level. Does anything happen if I collect all the code cubes including the ones in the extra levels?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @alex working on it, but it will literally take the entire game to do so, which is why I am asking to see if is worth it

Comment: multiple game guides report changes to the title screen and unlocking of the UFO under "unlockables" with the criteria of "100% completion"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collecting all 100 code cubes unlocks a rare sticker of President Haltmann.

[image: President Haltmann sticker]

Getting 100% completion on your save file will unlock the UFO power in the Ability Testing Area.